# unknown error on npm install "npm ERR! Unexpected token '.'" on using NVM-Windows, Node v17, NPM v8

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, nvm

This seems to be a semi-common error, but it's unclear to me what is causing it. I want to know what is causing this error and how can I resolve it.

Using NVM I have installed Node @latest (Version 17.4.0), which has installed npm's matching latest (v8.3.1).

```
PS C:\myRepo> node -v
v17.4.0
PS C:\myRepo> npm -v
8.3.1
PS C:\myRepo> nvm list

  * 17.4.0 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
    17.0.0
    15.6.0
    14.18.3
    14.15.4
    12.20.1
```

I then go to install a package dependency from npm and it gives me an error regardless of the package name:

```
PS C:\myRepo> npm install -g npm
npm ERR! Unexpected token '.'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\yodama\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-25T16_38_44_607Z-debug-0.log
```

And we can see the full debug log:

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'install',
0 verbose cli   '-g',
0 verbose cli   'npm'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@8.3.1
2 info using node@v17.4.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\yodama\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v17.4.0\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 3ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 3ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 3ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\yodama\.npmrc Completed in 4ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 4ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load Completed in 19ms
18 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 20ms
19 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
20 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 4ms
21 timing npm:load:display Completed in 7ms
22 verbose logfile C:\Users\yodama\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-25T16_38_44_607Z-debug-0.log
23 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 13ms
24 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
25 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
26 timing npm:load Completed in 42ms
27 verbose stack C:\Users\yodama\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v17.4.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\libnpmfund:1
27 verbose stack ../workspaces/libnpmfund
27 verbose stack ^
27 verbose stack
27 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
27 verbose stack     at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
27 verbose stack     at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)
27 verbose stack     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
27 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
27 verbose stack     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
27 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
27 verbose stack     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
27 verbose stack     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
27 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\yodama\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v17.4.0\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\reify-output.js:16:38)
27 verbose stack     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
28 verbose cwd C:\myRepo
29 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22000
30 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "npm"
31 verbose node v17.4.0
32 verbose npm  v8.3.1
33 error Unexpected token '.'
34 verbose exit 1
35 timing npm Completed in 262ms
36 verbose code 1
```

switching using nvm for windows to Node 14 fixes this issue:

```
PS C:\myRepo> nvm use 14.18.3
Now using node v14.18.3 (64-bit)
PS C:\myRepo> node -v 
v14.18.3
PS C:\myRepo> npm -v
6.14.15
PS C:\myRepo> npm i -g @microsoft/rush
npm WARN deprecated @opentelemetry/types@0.2.0: Package renamed to @opentelemetry/api, see https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js
C:\Program Files\nodejs\rush -> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\@microsoft\rush\bin\rush
C:\Program Files\nodejs\rushx -> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\@microsoft\rush\bin\rushx
+ @microsoft/rush@5.61.1
added 286 packages from 296 contributors in 26.69s
```

What is going wrong here? Is this an NVM issue, or a npm 8.x issue? I need to do testing in Node v17 for a specific bug, so just using the older versions of Node isn't a viable workaround.

Comment: I'm getting this exact same thing here, the exact same logs (invalid beginning . in libnpmfund file. Used NVM to install Node 17.4.0, get the error when I try to do `npm install`.

Comment: This is tracked by https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4340

Comment: as many answers are telling further down. Upgrade NVM (I am an windows) https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases

Comment: I had the same problem on windows. I had nvm version 1.1.7. After removing it and installing version 1.1.11, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 42):

Update the NVM-Windows to the newest version, which is by now
`1.1.9`

They've had fixed this issue, Workspace folder must be symlink.

The issue goes with NVM-Windows not NPM

Comment: I've upgraded to the version and doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I also needed to uninstall the already installed `node` and install it again (using new `nvm`)

Comment: Since `nvm v1.1.8` you can upgrade your old `nvm` without uninstalling anything (neither `nvm` nor `node`). I tried from `1.1.6` to `1.1.9` and zero problems. https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows#upgrading-nvm-windows

Answer (score 7):

1. Install Updated version of NVM
2. Uninstall node version
3. Reinstall node

this solved my issue

Answer (score 5):

use a lower version of node.

`nvm list` -> to see the installed node versions.

`nvm use <-version number->`

run `npm install` again.

Comment: 10.15.0 worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Download and install the update version of NVM Windows and run it. Then, download an LTS version of node

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by bringing the node version from **16.17.0** to **16.0.0**.

[**npm version -> 7.10.0**]

```
nvm install 16.0.0
nvm use 16.0.0

npm install
```

STACKTACE:

> verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' 
>  33 verbose stack
> at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
>  33 verbose stack     at
> wrapSafe 
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1055:15)
>  33 verbose
> stack     at Module._compile
>
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1090:27)
>  33 verbose stack
> at Object.Module._extensions..js
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
>  33 verbose stack     at
> Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
>  33 verbose
> stack     at Function.Module._load
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
>  33 verbose stack     at
> Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
>  33
> verbose stack     at require
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
>  33 verbose stack     at
> Object.
> (C:\Users<name>\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.17.0\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\reify-output.js:16:38)
>
>  33 verbose stack     at Module._compile
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)

Answer (score 0):

Just do: nvm use [lower version]
if you are using node version 17.9.0 than just downgrade the version and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I solved it by using node version 16.13.2

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get past this issue on my machine, originally posted steps [here](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/814#issuecomment-1458510073)

It appears that when you install newer versions of Node via `nvm` you need to make sure you do so in an **Administravtive** console. If you don't, it is failing to install `npm's` packages and there are a bunch of broken lib files.

I was getting these issues with `nvm-windows`, the fix for me was to

1. open an administrator console
2. run `nvm uninstall {brokenNodeVersion}`
3. then reinstall that version with `nvm install {brokenNodeVersion}`

I was able to tell what versions of node were broken on my machine by looking at the `libnpmfund` folder under the `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v{brokenNodeVersion}\node_modules\npm\node_modules\libnpmfund` and there would be a bunch of broken files with no extension. The contents of the files would just be one line like `..\packageName`

**After re-installing with an admin console** I see the broken files are gone and the folder looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For windows:
visit:[enter link description here](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases)
download 'nvm-update.exe' and update NVM to 1.1.10
uninstall your old node version, and reinstall node.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue and resolved it by upgrading nvm version to 1.1.11
https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases

Then,

> nvm uninstall <broken_version>

and

> nvm install <broken_version>